# How to have a profile url like facebook. (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, hyperlink

HI i am new to aspdotnet and want to ask how do I able to have a facebook like profile link for each of the registered user in the database.

**example:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/james
```

As you can see after .com there is a unique name. but my question: Is that name a folder or some kind of auto generated link?? How can I implement this kind of link for each of the registered user in my database?

well i can easy do it wit **GET** but I want to hide the id from the url.

Comment: You can achieve using URL routing. Please see below blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your RouteConfig.cs file in your App_Start folder.

The default route (www.facebook.com) is set to your `HomeController.Index()` method. You can tell that by the "defaults" parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In the example that you provided, "james" would be a string parameter for that `Index` method. Obviously, the signature to the method would be:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id) {
    // Do stuff
}
```